# Can I find out which friends of my friends who have viewed my profile?

Tags: privacy, facebook-profile

Is there any way I know which non-friend people have viewed my Facebook profile? For example, when someone is not my friend but is a friend of friend, if he or she views my profile, is there any way I can know?

Answer (score 4):

**Unlike LinkedIn, [this is not possible on Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/help/205685226136386).**

In fact, Facebook developers are explicitly prohibited from making any application that claim to be able to do so in accordance with the [Platform Policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/).

[image: Respect the Limits on Facebook's Functionality]

You can somewhat see who you chat with the most. See http://digiwonk.wonderhowto.com/how-to/track-who-views-your-facebook-profile-0147349/

Answer (score 0):

Nope, there is currently no way if doing this. Sorry...

Comment: Do you have a link to the documentation that says this?  Otherwise this is not very helpful.